# How to tunnel a tunneled connection?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, socks5

I have a `remote server A` to which I have `root access` and there is `server B in my local network` to which I have `non-sudo ssh access`. And I have `client C` which is an `ubuntu laptop` to which I have `root access` and `client D` which is an `Android phone`.

What I want to do is: I want to connect C and D to A via B so my traffic to the Internet from D first goes to C and from C to B(A and C and D are connected to the same network) and from B to A (B and A are remote) and from A to the Internet.

How can I achieve this?

Here is what I've done until now:
I run the following command on C:

```
ssh -D 127.227.11.98:8193 -fCqN <my username for B>@<the ip of B>
```

And I set `127.227.11.98:8193` as the socks5 proxy on firefox and I can connect to the Internet through B on C but still if I set that proxy on D when it's connected to the same network in doesn't work.

If it helps when I try to connect to VPN on C after this setupVPN on firefox says:

> It looks like you are being blocked by gov/school/ISP.

So what should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried `Proxycommand`? `Proxycommand ssh proxy -W %h:%p`